# Can't change background image of div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I added an event in my script that attempts to set the background-image of a div when a button is clicked. However, it is not working.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2 imageCard" style="float:left">
            <img class="card-img-top"
              src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/City/4-col/img%20(60).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
</div>

<div class="card-body">
          <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <p id="quoteSample">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
            <footer class="blockquote-footer" id="quoteAuthorSample">Someone famous in </footer>
          </blockquote> 
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.imageCard').click(function(){
    var imageSRC = ($(this).children('img').attr('src'));
    console.log(imageSRC)
    $('.card-body').css("background-image", "url(" + imageSRC + ")")
})
```

Console.log returns: 
https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/City/4-col/img%20(60).jpg

Comment: I tried your code and it should work, maybe you don't see the image because of its size, try to add `$('.card-body').css("background-size", "contain")` and `$('.card-body').css("background-repeat", "no-repeat")`

Comment: what do you getting in your console.log ?? and also include the html code of imageCard class.

Comment: What is .imageCard? It is not included in the html.

Answer (score 0):

It's like the button element `$('.imageCard')` isn't ready when the script tries to set the event listener (in this case: `click`).

For that, you have two options:

1. Put your script tag on the bottom of the page, that way they will load just before the HTML, so it will find the button that was already rendered.
2. Put your jquery click on a window load event, you can use like this:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       // Jquery click event
   });
   ```

   this code make sure that your javascript DOM code runs only when the document (HTML page) is rendered completely

I hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried out the code, but it didn't work. I included more info in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I find it out, the problem is in the concatenation assignment, the `background-image` CSS property can receive an URL by adding `url()` but this `url()` needs to receive a string, it works if you use it in plain js, but since you are adding this property by a function (using strings in the parameters), you need to be careful with the final return, example (you can try it on your browser console):

assign a string (link) to a variable

```
    var imageSRC = "https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/City/4-col/img%20(60).jpg"
```

and just type that, the return will be something like

```
    "url(" + imageSRC + ")" // "url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/City/4-col/img%20(60).jpg)"
```

Now, pay attention to the link inside the `url()`, it's not a string anymore, is just text, and `url()` must receive a string

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Use `"url('" + imageSRC + "')"` instead of `"url(" + imageSRC + ")"` that way you'll be putting the correct quotes on the parameter
2. Use javascript template strings (you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

   ```
   `url("${imageSRC}")`
   ```